# QR Code image generate with less black fill by Python?

Tags: python, odoo, python-3.7, qr-code, odoo-11

using is this [qrcode 7.3.1](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/)
 Python Package to Generate QR Code. I'm putting a long URL to generate the QR code with the url.
But the black fill is too much in the QR Code image.[image]

Is there any way to modify the QR to get less black fill in the image? I'll use this in odoo11 custom module

Comment: It looks fine to me. What do you mean by "too much black"?

Comment: it's ok.  But i want to get the image with black fill less.  now the black part is to much. when it's getting printed in small size . Hope you understand

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your printer settings, not the QR code.